# Searching a Java 8 string for the existence of words from a list

Tags: regex, java-8, apache-commons, blacklist

Java 8 here. I am given a list of blacklisted words/expressions as well as an input string. I need to determine if any of those blacklisted items appears in the input string:

```
List<String> blacklist = new ArrayList<>();

// populate the blacklist and "normalize" it by removing whitespace and converting to lower case
blacklist.add("Call for info".toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""));
blacklist.add("Travel".toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""));
blacklist.add("To be determined".toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""));
blacklist.add("Meals".toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""));
blacklist.add("Custom Call".toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""));
blacklist.add("Custom".toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""));

// obtain the input string and also "normalize" it
String input = getSomehow().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""));

// now determine if any blacklisted words/expressions appear inside the input
for(String blItem : blacklist) {
    if (input.contains(blItem)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IMPOSSSSSSSIBLE!")
    }
}
```

I *thought* this was working great until my `input` string contained the word "`Customer`" inside of it.

Since `custom` exists inside `customer`, the program is throwing an exception. **Instead**, I want it to be allowed, because "customer" is not a blacklisted word.

So I *think* the actual logic here is:

- If the input string contains a blacklist word...
- ...AND the blacklist word is preceded by either the beginning of the string or a non-alphabetical (`[a-z]`) character...
- ...AND the blacklist word is succeeded by either the end of the string or a non-alphabetical charatcer...
- ...then throw the exception

I *think* that would cover all my bases.

Does Java 8 or any (Apache or otherwise) "commons" library have anything that will help me here? For some reason I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this and making the code look elegant (I'm not sure how to check for the beginning/ending of a string from inside a regex, etc.).

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably use use a regex with `\b`(word boundary) , instead of `String.contains()`

Comment: as @BlackPearl has suggested, I would also use an anchored regex if you end the word "custom" with a "$" it implies that nothing can come after the m in custom, if you wanted to take it one step further you can anchor the beginning of custom with a "^" to imply that nothing comes before the c in custom :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-compile a list of Patterns for the given words.

`\b` indicates a word boundary. Adding a word boundary on both sides of a String will match the regex for exact words.

```
List<Pattern> blackListPatterns =
    blackList
        .stream()
        .map(
                word -> Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b")
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then you can match the word with the Pattern List.

If you are sure your word will not contain any metacharacters like `(`,`*` .etc, you can directly create your Pattern from the String instead of using `Pattern.quote()`, which is used to escape metacharacters.

```
for (Pattern pattern : blackListPatterns) {
    if (pattern.matcher(input).find()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IMPOSSSSSSSIBLE!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BlackPearl (+1) I think you're close, but keep in mind that `input` is a string and comes from end user input, so it could absolutely contain punctuation and meta characters. In reality, the `input` might be something like: "_Per customer request (make sure to follow up)_". In that example, no blacklist words were provided, so we want to allow it. Also, just to double check, will this word boundary concept (`\b`) include beginning/ending of string **as well as** non-numeric characters like whitespaces, punctuation, etc.? Thanks again!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup perhaps a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) is appropriate?

Comment: Non-word characters include all characters other than alphanumeric characters (-, - and -) and underscore (_).